# Retrieve local storage files on any OS using javascript or php or any other web language

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have retrieved pdf data from google drive in php using API. Now, I want to store this data as a txt in local storage of user & retrieve later to display. Is there any way to do this using web languages only???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly not the best way to accomplish your goal, but the answer is **maybe**.

It depends on how large the file is and what platforms you wish to support.

There is a PDF engine for JavaScript provided by Mozilla. It can load Base64 encoded data. Base64 encoded data can be stored in `localStorage`, which only accepts strings.

`localStorage` has size limitations that vary browser, platform, and possibly device. Remember also the the user can manipulate or modify `localStorage`, so this is not a *safe* place to store content.

- [Mozilla pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples)

Comment: Is there any way that I can make the user download the encoded pdf, then retrieve it & pass to pdf.js to view the file???

Comment: I you have the file on your server, you should be able to Base64 encode it in PHP. I don't do a lot of PHP work, though, so I'm not sure what the best/most appropriate process is. You should be able to load it by AJAX request, though.

Comment: Actually I want to store the file locally so that user doesn't have to load again & again

Answer (score 0):

For Drive operations, you should check out google Drive API
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

To save something on local, you would probably need to change the webpage contentType.